# llvm::Module be the left side of both operator .* and ->*

Tags: c++, pointers, llvm, unique-ptr

I was am reading [LLVM Tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html) and saw these statements (at different positions):

```
static std::unique_ptr<Module> TheModule;
TheModule.get();
TheModule->getFunction(arg);
```

But when I try putting this in my code:

```
TheModule->get();
```

I get error:

> myTest.cpp:116:16: error: no member named 'get' in 'llvm::Module' TheModule->get();

Why could `llvm::Module` be the left side of both `.*` and `->*`? And why does `TheModule.get()` work, but `TheModule->get()` doesn't?

Does this have anything to do with `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: Remember that `a->b` is syntactic sugar for `(*a).b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this have anything to do with std::unique_ptr?

Yes, it does.

It's the `std::unique_ptr`'s `get` you managed to call with `TheModule.get()`, which returns the managed pointer, `TheModule->get()` is not the same, it's equivalent to:

```
TheModule.get()->get();
(*TheModule).get();
(*TheModule.get()).get();
```

These are all the same and they call `get` on the managed `llvm::Module` instance. Of course, [`llvm::Module`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html) doesn't have `get`, that's why you're getting the error.

It's really not that surprising once you learn what [`operator*` and `operator->`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) of `std::unique_ptr` do. These operators exist, so you can work with smart pointers (syntactically) the same way as with raw ones. And [`std::unique_ptr::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) returns a raw pointer to the managed object.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the "arrow" operator `->` you access the contained pointer, when you use the dot operator `.` you access the `unique_ptr` object.

For example

```
TheModule.get()  // Calls std::unique_ptr<T>::get()

TheModule->getFunction(arg);  // Calls llvm::Module::getFunction()
```